# How to create URL & Read on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

How to create dynamic URL in **Codeigniter**?.

I've following **table** which stores basic article details:

```
 1. ID
 2. Article Title
 3. Content
 4. Tags
 5. Status
 6. Create Time
 7. Update Time
 8. Author ID
 9. Status
```

Now I want to know how to create dynamic URL, which holds `Page ID` & `Article Title`.

For example `http://www.domain.com/1/hello-codeigniter`

Now above sample URL, I am generating URL with `ID`  & `Article Title`.

1. ID for retrieve article content (When user clicks to article, get content from ID).
2. Article Title for Safe URL.

but I don't want to show `ID` from URL and still get content when user redirect to detail page.

### HERE IS MY CODE:

**View:** home_page.php

```
<div id="body">
        <?php for($i=0; $i<count($blogPosts); $i++): ?>
            <div class="post-preview">
                <?php
                    $postID = $blogPosts[$i]->id; // Get post ID
                    $postTitle = $blogPosts[$i]->title; // Get post Title
                    $urlTitle = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $postTitle); // Replacing space with dash
                    echo anchor('content/'.$postID.'/'.$urlTitle, $postTitle, array('title' => $postTitle)); // Get post URL
                    echo "<br />";
                ?>
            </div>
            <hr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
```

**Controller:** home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model("HomeModel"); // Load HomeModel
        $data['blogPosts'] = $this->HomeModel->blogPosts(); // Get blog posts data from blogPostsData function
        $this->load->view("home_page", $data);

    }

}
```

**Model:** HomeModel.php

```
class HomeModel extends CI_Model {

    public function blogPosts() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('blog_posts');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

After coding When I hover to anchor link I am getting this URL:

```
http://localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/content/1/My-First-Blog-Post!
```

How to hide `index.php`, `content` & `1` from URL.

One more thing is that When I clicked to link I am getting this error message:

```
An Error Was Encountered 
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I never used CI but I would throw a wild guess at `site_url()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `routes` for this purpose

To remove `index.php` use `.htaccess` with following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in `config.php`

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

To remove content from url remove content from anchor **in view**

```
echo anchor($postID.'/'.$urlTitle, $postTitle, array('title' => $postTitle)); // Get post URL
```

I don't think so you should remove `1` from url. If you remove it from url then how can you identify your post. So it will be good to keep it in url. Or if you want to remove then append this id at the end of post title like

```
http://localhost/codeIgniter/My-First-Blog-Post!-1
```

and explode the last element for id of post

```
An Error Was Encountered 
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

you are getting this error because in your url you added `!`. To make your application secure CI prevent special characters from url. So it would be best practice to don't use special characters in url except `_` and `-`.

**On your Controller**

```
class Content extends CI_Controller {
    function index($id, $name)
    {
        echo $name;// this contain book name 
        echo $id;// this contain book id

        //your code
    }
}
```

now in your routes `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['(:num)/(:any)']='content/index/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but can you please explain more with my example because I don't understand how to do this. I have updated my question with my example also give any suggestion in my code if needed.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have updated my code with your answer and everything is working perfect but is there any other way to pass id with hidden as I don't want show on URL. I have blog on WordPress and I can't see id from URL and it will return page content. I want to do same thing like WordPress is doing. Any idea?

Comment: What if I pass only title from URL and get page content by reading title. Is it proper way? Need your suggestion.

Comment: create a unique link on the basis of title then you can do it by title

Comment: if my answer helps you then please mark as right answer so other users can also get help from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the slug (Article Title for Safe URL) in the database, you don't need to expose the id at all. This would involve adding a column to your table though.

You can automate the slug generation on article creation using the `url_title()` as detailed [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/controller_name/method_name/<?php echo $item['name'] ?>/<?php echo $item['id'] ?>" alt="">click here to view</a>
```

So your URL looks like **`www.example.com/index.php/controller_name/method/book_name/book id`**

In Controller

```
function method_name($name, $id)
{
    echo $name;// this contain book name 
    echo $id;// this contain book id

    //Simply you can use this to get all data
    $result = $this->Model_name->get_book_details($id);//in model $id hold the id of book
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but can you please explain more with my example because I don't understand how to do this. I have updated my question with my example also give any suggestion in my code if needed.